# C Code result Explanation

Tags: c

Hello could someone explain to me why this code turns out to show this (00 11 21 32 42) on the command prompt when I run the program?

Here's the code:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    while (x < 5) {
        y = x - y;
        printf("%i%i ", x, y);
        x = x + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which part of the program don't you understand? Try to play computer and run that program in your head, that should show you why it prints that.

Comment: do printf("%d%d ", x, y); Instead..

Comment: Invest in a pencil and paper. Have two columns one called x and y and write initial values along with their subsequent values within the loop

Comment: @EdHeal No space for two registers in your head? :D

Comment: @thejh - It was a metaphor.

Comment: @thejh A pen and paper table of the changing values of `x` & `y` is very useful to novice computer science students learning the concept of loops. @EdHeal's suggestion is quite constructive!

Comment: @awashburn - Thank you. If you require paper so be it. (BTW sometimes I require the use of those facilities to figure out what is going on)

Comment: @JoeDF Why, and how is that relevant to the question?

Comment: @EdHeal sorry for ranting, you're right :D

Comment: @thejh - For good will you have received a +1

Comment: @JimBalter lol, i got confused somehow.. my mistake :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program loops 5 times, while `x` is in the range `[0,4]`, printing the values of `x` and `y`
The statement `y = x - y` tells us that `y`'s current value will depend on the current value of `x` and `y`'s previous value

```
                   x   y
x = 0  ==>  y = 0 (0 - 0)
x = 1  ==>  y = 1 (1 - 0)
x = 2  ==>  y = 1 (2 - 1)
x = 3  ==>  y = 2 (3 - 1)
x = 4  ==>  y = 2 (4 - 2)
```

Comment: @user2227961 If you found my answer helpful, consider accepting the answer by clicking the green check mark underneath the vote count

Answer (score 2):

first iteration:

`x=0`
`y=0-0=0`

second:

`x=1` `y=1-0=1`

third:

`x=2` `y=2-1=1`

forth:

`x=3` `y=3-1=2`

fifth:

`x=4` `y=4-2=2`

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of the loop, x is incremented by 1 and y (the second digit) is the result of the CURRENT x MINUS the PREVIOUS y.